# Необходима ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Щадить врага Джонс не умел, и сам не ждал от него пощады.

Answer (score 2):

**Щадить врага Джонс не умел, и сам не ждал от него пощады.**

Запятая нужна, это сложносочиненное предложение. **Сам ― местоименное существительное** в роли подлежащего во втором предложении.

**САМ**, самого; м.; I. **местоим. сущ**. 1. Указывает **на лицо или предмет**, которые лично, непосредственно производят действие или испытывают какое-л. состояние. Скажите об этом сами. Всех угощал, а сам и не притронулся. 2. **Указывает на лицо или предмет**, которые совершают действие самостоятельно, без постороннего вмешательства. Всё сделаю сам. Ругать некого: сами выбирали. Кто тарелку разбил? - Сама разбилась.